# Displaying a hidden field

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to set a hidden textblock that I want to appear upon a button click. I am using XAML and Caliburn.Micro.

Seems like a simple task, but I have to learn it first!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To hide**

[Visibility.Collapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx)

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed">
```

**To display**

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Visible">
```

programmatically something like this in your button click

```
textboxid.Visibility = 
    ( textboxid.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ) ? 
       Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to change from Collapsed/Hidden to Visible on a button click.

Comment: @Josh - that you can do by programaticaly by assinging is and writritng like textboxid.Visiblity = Visiblity.Collapse; or textboxid.Visiblity = Visiblity.Visible; write this code in button click